# PowerQuery ODBC connection revokes password: due to auto-refresh?

Tags: passwords, microsoft-excel-2016, odbc, power-query

I have a nice PowerQuery query that connects with ODBC to a database. Our passwords change every month. When I enter GetAndTransform to edit the query, that time of the month - even if I don't explicity refresh the query: PQ revokes my ODBC password for all apps on my PC. I assume PQ automatically tries to connect and then fails with wrong password 3+ times. Is there some solution e.g. rather disable PQ auto-reconnect and let user retype the password manually every time? Which should solve the problem. It's kind of chicken-and-egg problem since I cannot of course change the passsword in PQ without entering the query in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't struck your exact scenario, but this is probably worth a try:

If you can find the **Query Options** window (usually in the sub-menu under the **New Query** button), then navigate to **Current Workbook / Data Load / Background** and uncheck **Allow data preview to download in the background**.

That should put the query refresh timing under your control.  You'll need to hit the Refresh Preview button in the PQ Editor ... a lot.